# Maxima of complicated function

Tags: polynomials, maxima-minima

I've been trying to find (analytically) the maximum of the function

$$ f(x,\lambda,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{x}{\lambda} \right)\left[\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^2 + \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} }  + \left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\right],$$

with respect to $x$, in the interval $0<x<\lambda$. Here, $\lambda$ and $t$ can simply be treated as constants (with, generally, $t\sim 1$). Setting the first derivative to zero yields

$$  0  = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}(\lambda -x)\left[ 2\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^2 + \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} }  + (2t+1) \right]- \sqrt{\left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^2 + \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} }\left[\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^2 + \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} }  + \left(t+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\right],
$$

which I cannot seem to solve analytically; even my computer finds this difficult.

Does anyone have any other techniques I could try in order to determine the location of this maximum in terms of $\lambda$ and $t$? Even constraining the location of the maximum will be useful, but I am unsure of how to do this!

Comment: Is there any restriction on $t$? Also, the maximum is at $x = 0$ for $t$ sufficiently large with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: Hey @VarunVejalla, thanks for the reply. Technically t is unrestricted, but should probably be considered a parameter of order unity.

Comment: You can "simplify" the problem to finding the roots of a degree $7$ polynomial. Then, plug in for $x$ the roots of this polynomial that are within the bounds, as well as the bounds themselves, and take the maximum of those values.